# Find Pattern in String in Python

Tags: regex, string, substring

I have the string, containing numbers(0~9), characters(A~Z) and brackets("()"). and if containing brackets, must treat the brackets and the number(or the character) inside as together. For example, "(G)8(8)(G)4(C)(G)8(8)" or "(2)2(6)2(6)2(2)2(8)". And then I need to find the pattern in this string(not overlapping). Here, the string, I mean it occurs twice or more. Take

```
"(2)2(6)2(6)2(2)2(8)"
```

for example, the pattern I want to extract is

```
"2(6)", "(2)2" and "(6)2"
```

, because they occur twice. and the string

```
"(G)8(8)(G)4(C)(G)8(8)"
```

, I can extract

```
"(G)8(8)"
```

. I know re.compile(r"(.+?)\1+").findall(string), this function can find the pattern, but it can't apply to my situation. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: what is the pattern to define term: `group together`? is it follow this rule: `(word|digit)digit(word|digit)digit....` or `digit(word|digit)digit...` ?

Comment: I mean the pattern ")2(6" is not accepted, the brackets and the number(or the character) inside needs to be together

Comment: Doesn't the second string also contains `8(8)` value that meets your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the second string also contains `8(8)` value that meets your requirements since it occurs twice in the string.

Since the matches you seek can be overlapping, you need a capturing group inside an unanchored positive lookahead:

```
(?=((?:\([A-Z0-9]+\)|\d){2,}).*\1)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rV7rxI/1).

Here, the `((?:\([A-Z0-9]+\)|\d){2,})` captures into Group  1 two or more sequences of `(`+uppercase ASCII letters or digits, 1 or more+`)` or a digit (`\d`). The `\1` will require the same value to appear somewhere after any 0+ chars (add `re.S` modifier if you need to check across multiple lines).

Here is an [online Python demo](http://ideone.com/Dna9hr):

```
import re
ss = ['(2)2(6)2(6)2(2)2(8)', '(G)8(8)(G)4(C)(G)8(8)']
r = r'(?=((?:\([A-Z0-9]+\)|\d){2,}).*\1)'
for s in ss:
    print(s)
    print(re.findall(r, s)) #print([x.group(1) for x in re.finditer(r, s)])
    print("---------")
```

Output:

```
(2)2(6)2(6)2(2)2(8)
['(2)2', '2(6)', '(6)2']
---------
(G)8(8)(G)4(C)(G)8(8)
['(G)8(8)', '8(8)']
---------
```